# Wireless Communication in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am trying to send a packet from sender to receiver using C++ codes.

I have created a Ned file with 2 wireless host, and a c++ file for each.

I am having this error:

```
***check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (omnetpp::cPacket*)Packet to type 'inet::physicallayer::WirelessSignal *' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio) Network1.receiver.wlan[0].radio (id=96), at t=0***
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Here are the codes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>


using namespace omnetpp;
using namespace inet;

class Sender : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    cMessage *packet;
    simtime_t packetGenerationInterval;
    int packetSize;
    cModule *server;
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Sender);

void Sender::initialize()
{
    packetGenerationInterval = par("packetGenerationInterval");
    packetSize = par("packetSize");
    packet = new cMessage("Packet");
    server =getModuleByPath("receiver");
    scheduleAt(simTime(), packet);  // Schedule the first packet generation
}

void Sender::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == packet) {
        // Generate packet content and header
        std::string packetContent = "Packet from Sender1";

        cPacket *newPacket = new cPacket("Packet");
        newPacket->setByteLength(packetSize);
        
        sendDirect(newPacket, server, "radioIn", 0);

        scheduleAt(simTime() + packetGenerationInterval, packet);
    }

}


#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class Receiver : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Receiver);

void Receiver::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->isPacket()) {
        //cPacket *packet = check_and_cast<cPacket *>(msg);
        EV << "Received packet: " << msg << std::endl;
       }
}
```

I think the issue is with the type of packet created.

Comment: The C++ code you added lacks syntax highlighting. I suggest you edit your post so that the code is highlighted and other users can help you better. The code is lacking libraries in several #include directives. I think if you fix these two more users will be keen on helping you :) Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in omnet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, am new in stack overflow so I will try to add what you've suggested.

Comment: I edited for you. Next time you have a code block. Paste it, select the code and then you can format with "ctrl+k"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (quite) a bit of confusion here. You have not mentioned, but you are also using the INET Framework. Based on the error message, youre `receiver` module is a `StandardHost` with a configured wireless (WiFi) interface and with all the protocol levels built in (i.e. TCP/IP, link layer etc). On the other hand, your Sender module is **NOT** a `StandardHost`, but just a pure OMNeT++ simple module. (The `Receiver` module you have provided is not used at all in your simulation).

So, your basic simple module tries to send something to the StandardHost, but its wireless interface does not understand it, which is to be expected. The INET framework has quite a complex architecture to simulate the physical reality and all the protocol behavior. On the other hand, your model is the most basic one, one can imagine. I would suggest take a look at the INET [Wireless Tutorial](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc) and use `StandardHost`s both for the sender and receiver modules to be compatible.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In fact in the ned file I have defined both sender and receiver the same way as wireless host. Wouldn't the code line "server =getModuleByPath("receiver")" refer to the receiver? I am sorry I am still confused about where my code goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, it would refer to the receiver, however what the server's actual type is, depends on what you wrote in the top level network NED file. Without seeing the NED files, it's hard to tell, however I'm fairly sure you have a `receiver: WirelessHost` line somewehere there. But this is not the main problem with your project. First you have to decide whether you want to use INET framework, or you want to implement your whole wireless simulation model from scratch (using only OMNeT++ API)

Comment: I want to use the INET framework. what do you suggest to simulate this correctly? 
Please note that I have some tasks that will be built on this c++ code that is why I did not use directly the .ini file.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at the wireless tutorial to see how to set up various wireless scenarios. To generate packets using your own C++ code, you should implement an **application** module and you should probably use UDP protocol. Take a look at the UdpBasicApp model.